# Get all the Cidr Blocks associated to a specific VPC with Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to retrieve all the cidr blocks exists in a specific VPC but it only retrieves the primary one.
For example, when I run the following cmdlet:
(Get-EC2Vpc -Region  -VpcId ).Cidrblock
I get only the primary one although I've another cidr block associated to the same VPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$myVpc = Get-EC2Vpc -VpcId <your_id_here>
$myVpc.CidrBlockAssociationSet.CidrBlock
```

or one-liner
`$(Get-EC2Vpc -VpcId <your_id_here>).CidrBlockAssociationSet.CidrBlock`

Either of those should give you the output you need.